# can't run 'wget|curl|git clone' or 'irb' in MobaXterm

Tags: windows, command-line, cygwin, mobaxterm

A collegaue recommended me to try out MobaXterm (Personal) for my *nix on Windows (7) needs.

It's promissing but I have the following problems:

1. although I had installed ruby (tried the `apt-get` and plugin method too), I can't run `irb` at all. `irb` is in `$PATH` (`/bin/irb`, and I did try to run it like `/usr/bin/irb` too), and when I try to run it, almost nothing happens... wait... wait... then prompt gets back with the unsuccesful mark.
2. the same story with `wget|curl|git clone http://...`.

Do you have any idea, where to start with this issue?

Answer (score 4):

I have also faced the same problem, and one of my expert colleague indicates me that the libopenssl100 is missing.
So, with a `apt-get install libopenssl100` it works for me (at least for curl).

Hope it helps

Comment: Sadly I got the same answer from their support, but still not working :-/

Answer (score 1):

Similar error for me; not able to run git, curl and wget. Even also issues with ssh at some point.

For the specific case of cURL, I got this:

> D:/Windows/Users/x/MobaXterm/slash/bin/curl.exe: error while loading
>   shared libraries: ?: cannot open shared object file: No such file or
>   directory

Accessing the folder and running the curl binary there would lead to an error indicating that `cygpsl-5.dll` did not exist. Following [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1078262) I searched for the DLL at the [Cygwin package search](https://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-grep.cgi?grep=cygpsl-5&arch=x86_64). This indicated possible related packages.

Finally, doing the following solved the issue:

```
apt-get install libpsl5
```

You may repeat this for any other missing driver, or even replacing binaries at the folder specified in your error.

Answer (score 0):

If it doesn't work for you, then maybe libopenssl100 is already installed.

For me this helped

```
apt-cyg remove libopenssl100
apt-cyg install libopenssl100
```

That was the fix for my last issue with this.