# Tidy reports missing library cygtidy-0-99-0.dll

Tags: cygwin, libraries

I am trying to execute `tidy.exe` but get the following error message.

> /cygwin/bin/tidy.exe: error while loading shared libraries: cygtidy-0-99-0.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Which package should I install to fulfill this dependency? Why it is not installed by default with `tidy` package?

Comment: Missing library is probably the most abused question for cygwin. It is reported tons of time and as David show is the most easy to solve looking on the cygwin website.

Comment: I you are the one to downvote it then shame on you. :) The solution to this problem was not the search engine of cygwin. Reinstalling the library was what solved the issue.

Comment: Asking questions without making a minimal effort to look for the solution is not the scope of this website.  `https://cygwin.com/faq.html#faq.using.missing-dlls`

Comment: I did look for the solution. Google returned no results when it comes to this library. So start judging yourself in the first place before you start judging the others.

Comment: You are supposed to use a minimum of effort also asking google.  `http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[cygwin]+missing+dll`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Missing library `cygtidy-0-99-0.dll`

> Which package should I install to fulfill this dependency?

You need the `libtidy0_99_0` package.

---

#### How can I find out which package `cygtidy-0-99-0.dll` is in?

The easiest way to find the package containing a particular command or file is to use the [Cygwin Package Search](https://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-grep.cgi) page:

1. Open the [Cygwin Package Search](https://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-grep.cgi) web page in your web browser.

   <kbd>[image]</kbd>
2. Select either the 32 bit or 64 bit version of Cygwin as appropriate for your installation.
3. Enter the name of the program you are looking for (`cygtidy-0-99-0.dll`).
4. Click "Go" on the web page.

   <kbd>[image]</kbd>
5. Click "libtidy0_99_0-20090325-1" to confirm you have the correct package:

   ```
    2013-05-31 06:38      303123 usr/bin/cygtidy-0-99-0.dll
   ```

---

#### Why it is not installed by default with the `tidy` package?

I cannot reproduce your issue. However, `cygtidy-0-99-0.dll` was already installed here before I installed `tidy`. I don't know which package installed it.

```
DavidPostill@Hal /f/test
$ ll /usr/bin/*tidy*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 DavidPostill None 303123 May 31  2013 /usr/bin/cygtidy-0-99-0.dll
-rwxr-xr-x 1 DavidPostill None  24595 May 18 14:57 /usr/bin/tidy.exe
```

It is possible there is a missing dependency in the Cygwin installer.

Comment: Thanks for this great answer! I already have `libtidy0_99_0-20090325-1` installed and still the library is not there. If it comes to the package `tidy-debuginfo-20090325-1` it is not available at all in the installer. I have the latest version of it, namely `2.874`.

Comment: @Jagger Hmm. `tidy-debuginfo-20090325-1` contains a different dll - `cygtidy-0-99-0.dll.dbg` - I'm not sure I understand your comment.

Comment: @Jagger What is the output of `ls /usr/bin/*tidy*`? What is the exact `tidy` command you are trying to run?

Comment: The output of `ls /usr/bin/*tidy*` is `/usr/bin/tidy.exe`. The exact command I run is `tidy -im my_file.html`.

Comment: @Jagger reinstall `libtidy0_99_0-20090325-1`

Comment: The dependency is correct in the setup.ini file.

Comment: @matzeri Perhaps the file got deleted by mistake. In any case, a reinstall fixed the issue.

Comment: @DavidPostill It can also be glitch in the installation or interferance from other programs. It is relative common issues